# Android, PHP and MySQL

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, json

i'm trying to develop an android application that connects to a MySQL database.

I'm using PHP as a web Service parsing the data from a JSON array.

But when i click to do the process nothing happens, the data is not added to the database.
First i change the code and i'm using `AsynTask<>` for avoiding the RunningOnMainThread Exception, but y can't make it work.

Any suggestions?

Here's the code:

PHP:

```
<?php
$hostname ="localhost";
$database ="traffic_qro";
$username ="root";
$password ="";

$localhost = mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password);

mysql_select_db("traffic_qro");
$name = $_REQUEST['driver_name'];
$number = $_REQUEST['driver_number'];
$plate = $_REQUEST['driver_plate'];
$brand = $_REQUEST['driver_brand'];
$model = $_REQUEST['driver_model'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO users VALUES('".$name."', '".$number."', '".$plate."', '".$brand."', '".$model."'');";

$res = mysql_query($sql);

if(!$res) {
    echo "Error in query: ".mysql_error();
}
mysql_close();
?>
```

DBTask.java

```
class DBTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    protected Void doInBackground(String... args) {
        InputStream is = null;
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("driver_name", args[0]));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("driver_number", args[1]));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("driver_plate", args[2]));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("driver_brand", args[3]));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("driver_model", args[4]));
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                    "http://192.168.1.85/traffic_qro/add_client_doc.php");
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
            Log.e("log_tag", is.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection" + e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String feed) {
        // TODO: check this.exception
        // TODO: do something with the feed
    }
}
```

Implementation od DBTask.java

```
new DBTask().execute(driver_name, drvr_num, driver_car_plate,
                    driver_car_brand, driver_car_model);
```

Comment: Are you receiving a response from the remote PHP server?

Answer (score 0):

You've got an error in your SQL statement, specifically around `'".$model."'');` (two single quotes after $model):

Change:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users 
        VALUES('".$name."', '".$number."', '".$plate."', '".$brand."', '".$model."'');";
```

to

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users 
        VALUES('".$name."', '".$number."', '".$plate."', '".$brand."', '".$model."');";
```

To check for errors like this, use:

```
$res = mysql_query($sql, $localhost) or trigger_error(mysql_error($localhost));
```

Comment: I change the double single quotes error, but keep doing nothing. I don't know if i have explained myself correctly, let me know if is the case. PS: Sorry about my english. :/